# 'Segmentation fault (core dumped)' with case

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

'*Segmentation fault (core dumped)*' appears when I execute the following program. However, if I use the *if...else* statement it doesn't give me any error. What is the reason of the error message in this case? How can I use the *case* statement without error?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

/*
    if (argc == 1){
        cout << argv[0] << endl;
    }else
    if (argc == 2){
        int n;
        n = atoi(argv[0]);
        cout << n << endl;
    }
*/
    switch (argc){
        case 1:{
            cout << argv[0] << endl;
        }
        case 2:{
            int n;
            n = atoi(argv[1]);
            cout << n << endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no `break` within your `switch` block. Hence, every case will *fallthrough*. This invokes Undefined Behavior when `argc` is `1`. You should `break` out of the *switch* when you do not want a *fallthrough*.

```
switch (argc){
    case 1:{
        cout << argv[0] << endl;
        break;
    }
    case 2:{
        int n;
        n = atoi(argv[1]);
        cout << n << endl;
        break;
    }
}
```

From C++17, when compilers warn you about implicit *fallthroughs* (its not required to), you can use the attribute `[[fallthrough]]` to declare that your *fallthrough* is intentional.

Comment: @RogerLipscombe... Ooops. My mistake. Corrected. Thank you